# use contentediable in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have a table with cell contentediable. When I use chrome it works, but it don't work on IE. Can I fix this problem if I want to use IE instead of chrome?

```
  <td contentediable > </td>
```

Comment: doesn't work with ie7 http://caniuse.com/#search=contenteditable 

why do you need this for? can't you just use textarea?

Comment: You have a typing error, it is `contenteditable` and not `contentediable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please follow this

```
<td><div contenteditable>fdgrgf</div></td>
```

hope this helps